# How do I use background fetch in iOS 13 to update pdfs?

Tags: swift, background-process, background-fetch, ios-pdfkit

I watched many videos and read many articles about the new background fetch in iOS 13, but I am still in the dark. I am making a dining app. Amongst other things I am presenting the menu for "today", which is changing every day. So far I use the PDFKit to show an example menu of a restaurant and have the menu for "today" and "tomorrow" downloaded into my project folder, but I want to use background fetch to get the menu updated every day. So far I only understood that I will have to check the boxes for "background fetch" and "background processing", where the refresh task is used to update content and the processing is used to clean up.

I am also wondering if I need my own website where I upload the pdf to retrieve the url from there. In the end I have to update an image and some labels as well, but I hope that I'll be able to do that on my own once I understood the principles.

I show you my code and screenshot of my view controller to give you a better understanding of my app so far.

```
    let today = "AmericanDinerMenu" // PDF 1 with menu for today
    let tomorrow = "ConniesDinerMenu" // PDF 2 with menu for tomorrow

    func activePDF(PDF: String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: PDF, ofType: "pdf") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I hope you can help me. Thank you!